# Xcode doesn't start

Tags: macos, mac, xcode

I recently downloaded Xcode directly from apple.com (I didn't use the App Store). Now I try to open it, but it just says "Checking Xcode", it loads until the progress bar reaches 100% and then it does nothing.

What can I do?

[image: Window]

Answer (score 8):

1. Delete all files at

   ```
   ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.*
   ```
2. Manually install Developer Tools from Terminal by running

   ```
   xcode-select --install
   ```
3. Reinstall "XcodeSystemResources.pkg" from contents of Xcode.app itself

   ```
   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/Packages/XcodeSystemResources.pkg
   ```

Finally Xcode 9.0.1 (9A1004) worked perfectly.

Comment: This also helps when Xcode was installed and suddenly doesn't work. Here there was just some Xcode bounces and Xcode closed again. After running the above, works fine again.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you said that you downloaded Xcode from Apple.com, so you must have downloaded a beta version. The same issue also happened to me when the Xcode 7 beta came out. For whatever reason this sometimes happens when trying to run the betas.

Unless there is a big reason why you can't (some feature you need for app development), just download Xcode from the Mac App Store and you shouldn't run into this issue again.

Comment: The reason why I downloaded it from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/ was that I couldn't download it from the App Store.

Comment: @Alex How come?

Comment: Because it took extremely long and I wasn't sure if it was downloading at all. So I canceled the download.

Comment: developer.apple.com doesn't only host beta versions. The Xcode Code Signature verification (the screenshot) takes a very long time, since it must verify around 7GB worth of data. Just download it from the App Store, and remember it should take a while. You can check on the progress by going into the Launchpad.

Comment: I downloaded it now from App Store, it works. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS High Sierra (10.13.4) I started XCode (9.3) and it immediately quit without any message. The solution was to

> **Find and close any running app that takes too much system resources (CPU, memory)!**

In my case Android Studio got stuck and was running with 400% CPU power.

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

I had a simmilar issue. I solved it following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34617452/how-to-update-xcode-from-command-line):

1. removing the old tools (`sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`)
2. install xcode command line tools again (`xcode-select --install`).

Answer (score 0):

I use `xed .` to open my project/workspace.

I accidentally hit `xed /` and that some how put Xcode is a weird state that upon opening any project Xcode would just open a spinning wheel.

I restarted and deleted my derived data a couple times but nothing worked.

What fixed it was opening a single file with `xed` i.e. I just did `xed foo.swift` and I was then able to open projects in Xcode.